# Getting "insufficient access rights on cross reference id" when trying to create a record and set the contact lookup field

Tags: apex

I am aware that this error can be fixed by giving the user permissions to the object being referenced but is there a work around for creating records for users without allowing them access to the cross referenced object?

What I am trying to do is have users submit a form and then create a registration custom object on the back end. I am hoping there is a way to do this without actually giving the user access to that object. Possibly there is a better way to set the contactId lookup field than what I am currently doing?

Code below:

```
    public static Event_Registration__c createEventReg(Id recordId, String registrationType){
    Id userId =UserInfo.getUserId();
    Event_Registration__c newReg = new Event_Registration__c();
    newReg.Event__c = recordId;
    newReg.Contact__c = [SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE ID = :userId].ContactId;
    System.debug(newReg.Contact__c);
    newReg.Registration_Type__c = registrationType;
    newReg.In_Attendance__c = true;

    insert newReg;
```

Javascript:

```
        createReg: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('hi');
    var action = component.get("c.createEventReg");
        console.log('got apex')
    var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log(recId);
    var regType = component.get("v.registrationType");
    console.log(regType);
        action.setParams({ recordId : recId, registrationType : regType });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('State: ' + state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('Record is Created Successfully');
            component.set('v.registered', true);
            component.set('v.isOpen', false);
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log('incomplete');
            // do something
        }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.log(errors);
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: what is the sharing mode for the apex class?

Comment: This sort of issue is (almost?) always related to sharing rules (hence cropredy's question).

Comment: The solution is to turn off sharing rule application in the code.

Comment: I did not manually set a sharing mode so whatever the default is I suppose. I will turn off sharing rules for this class and see if that helps.

Comment: Adding " Without Sharing" to my class allows me to create these records without error. Thanks Y'all!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my class was trying to implement charing rules which restricted access for users to create the records themselves. After specifying `public Without Sharing class EventsController {` I was able to create the records as a dummy user.